# How to instantiate and use subsequent array inside ngFor?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

```
*ngFor="let arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'sla']; let item of arr; let i = index;"
```

Why when providing that the instantiation of `arr` before `let item of arr;` does this raise an exception of `[object Object]` or rather why can't I do this?

The reason I don't want to do `let item of [...]` is because then I would also have to put this information into my `.ts` file which I don't want to do.

I want to have the ability to go back and reference this array from inside my html so *I need a way of refferencing the declared array* without instantiating it in the data file.

stack trace for reference:

```
ERROR 
Error: [object Object]
Stack trace:
resolvePromise@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:795:31
resolvePromise@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:766:17
scheduleResolveOrReject/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:844:17
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:425:17
onInvokeTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:4956:24
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:17
Zone.prototype.runTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:192:28
drainMicroTaskQueue@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:602:25
```

Comment: you can try this `*ngFor="let item of ['foo', 'bar', 'sla']; let i = index;"`

Comment: @Sanoj_V But this means I can't get the length of that array afterwards as it's anonymous.

Comment: you can get the length of array by doing this: `*ngFor="let item of ['foo', 'bar', 'sla'] as arr; let i = index;"` in your html `{{arr.length}}`

Comment: Okay that works, can you post an answer?

Comment: Yes, sure @li. x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to instantiate you array as would would normally but afterwards you need to add `as` which will allow you to make a reference to the array in html:

```
*ngFor="let item of ['foo', 'bar', 'sla'] as arr; let i = index;"
```

Afterwards you can then just say `{{arr.length}}` as expected.